# How an I confirm my Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard is encrypted?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, encryption

I have a MacBook pro Retina 15, Late 2013 running Mojave. I also have an off brand Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard ( [GeneralKeys PX-4068-675](http://www.generalkeys.de/Bluetooth-Volltastatur-fuer-Macbooks-mechanische-X-PX-4068-919.shtml) ).

The keyboard connects fine to the MacBook WITHOUT asking for a pin ... but I'm not clear if the connection is using/requiring encryption.

**Is here a way to verify it is encrypted?**

Comment: Does the manufacturer claim the connection is encrypted?

Comment: @GrahamMiln I'm not sure. I don't think so. But the manual is in German (I'm an English speaking expat) - and my German language skills aren't so great. But looking through the manual, and the website, I simply don't see it mentioned.

Comment: See this answer for some useful info:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287013/119271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you should assume your keyboard is not secure. Much depends on who is likely to be attacking you – prankster or nation state:

> While Bluetooth has its benefits, it is susceptible to denial of service attacks, eavesdropping, man-in-the-middle attacks, message modification, and resource misappropriation.

These two questions on related StackExchanges give a good overview:

- [Is Bluetooth 4.0 traffic encrypted by default/design?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100554/is-bluetooth-4-0-traffic-encrypted-by-default-design)
- [How secure is a bluetooth keyboard against password sniffing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/137091/how-secure-is-a-bluetooth-keyboard-against-password-sniffing)

Hopefully you can secure the environment in which the keyboard can broadcast.

## WireShark

The WireShark tool maybe able to intercept the Bluetooth traffic. See [Bluetooth Smart Wireshark Plugin](https://lacklustre.net/bluetooth/wireshark.html) for a guide. Also see [Bluetooth Smart Security](https://lacklustre.net/bluetooth/) for more technical details.